# get instance of inner class in java singleton

Tags: java, singleton, inner-classes

I have the following arrangement (not showing all fields and methods):

```
public class MyClass implements myClassInterface{

    public static MyClass getInstance(){
       return INSTANCE;
    }

    public class Inner implements innerStuff{
        @Override
         public void doInnerWork(Object param){
         }
    }
}
```

I need to access `doInnerWork(param)`. How do I do that? I try many things but they all fail including:

```
new (MyClass.getInstance().Inner()).doInnerWork(param);
```

thanks for helping.

Comment: Where is `innerStuff`? Why not `InnerStuff`? Where is `INSTANCE` declared? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Where is your instance of `Inner`? After you have an instance of `Inner`, you could do something like: `MyClass.getInstance().getInnerInstance().doInnerWork(Object);`

Comment: If that's really what you want, you'd better provide a createInner() method in MyClass that creates an instance and returns it. The code will be clearer and the class easier to use: `MyClass.getInstance().createInner().doInnerWork()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyClass.getInstance().new Inner().doInnerWork(param);`
Note that this will create a new inner class every time (it won't be a singleton).

Comment: Perhaps only creating 1 instance of `Inner` would be better so you don't have to keep creating a new instance every time you want to invoke that method.

Comment: I agree, but in that case - why would you need this inner anyway... you can have its functionality as part of the singleton,

Comment: Judging from how general the OP's class is, perhaps he is trying to accomplish that isn't so obvious. But I agree, the inner class, in the OP's example, seems very pointless.

Answer (score 0):

To create an instance of a nested class `Inner`, where you want it to be nested inside some object `obj`, the syntax is

```
obj.new Inner()
```

So in your case you probably want

```
MyClass.getInstance().new Inner().doInnerWork(param);
```

I'm not saying this will give you the results you want, but that's the syntax.